# Pointer to Reference/Address parameter

Tags: c++, pointers, memory

Sorry about the confusing title, did not know what to title it.
I have this function:

```
static void smooth5(IntVector*& v)
{
    IntVector* tmp = new IntVector();
    for(int i=0; i<v->size(); i+=2)
        tmp->push_back(v->at(i));
    delete v;
    v = tmp;
}
```

and in the main I do this:

```
IntVector* v = new IntVector();

v->push_back(0);
v->push_back(1);
v->push_back(2);
v->push_back(3);

smooth5(v);

//print the contents of v
```

When I print the contents of v, the output is 0 2.
But I did not understand what

```
IntVector*& v
```

really means when v is a pointer to an object on the heap. Can someone please explain?

Comment: It is a reference to a pointer. There is no pointer to reference in C++, it simply cannot exist.

Comment: It's a reference to a pointer to an `IntVector`.

Comment: It's passing the pointer by reference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`IntVector*&` declares a reference to a pointer.  Using this as a function argument allows `smooth5` to modify the caller's copy of `v`.

It is similar to but more readable than passing a pointer to a pointer - `IntVector**`.

In your example, `smooth5` deletes the caller's `IntVector` and points it to its `tmp` variable instead.

Comment: I personally understood it that it is a pointer to the address of the pointer v on the stack. 
Why is it a REFERENCE to a pointer and not the opposite?

Comment: @simonc in fact a pointer to pointer and a pointer reference are not exactly equivelent. A reference can never be NULL.

Comment: +1 (not debating the more-readable; it is , however, not root-*null-able* like a dbl-pointer can be =P)

Comment: @IvayloStrandjev, WhozCraig, very good point, thanks, I've tried to modify the language here

Comment: @TheNotMe Are you asking about naming `*&` "reference to pointer" vs "pointer to reference"?  The ordering feels natural to me but that may just be habit.  You start out with a pointer and want to pass it by reference... "reference to pointer" seems to accurately describe that.

Comment: One thing left to understand: we deleted v (means, I think, we deleted the vector itself from the heap) and then we try and do v = tmp. isnt v=tmp a reference to a deleted memory block on the heap (v) ?

Comment: @TheNotMe `delete v` deletes the `IntVector` `v` points to.  `v` remains a valid variable on the stack so can safely be written to with the address of `tmp`

Answer (score 1):

This is not a pointer to reference but a reference to a pointer. This means that instead of passing a copy of the pointer to the function you pass a reference to it. So as a result any modifications you do to the pointer in the function `smooth5` will affect the argument you pass to it in this case the pointer `v`.

Answer (score 0):

What `IntVector*& v` in your code means depends who's reading it.
When the compiler reads it, it means that `v` is a reference to
a pointer to `IntVector` (which is a typedef to
`std::vector<int>`?).  When I read it, it means that the author
of the code probably didn't understand how C++ works, and is
trying to adapt Java or C# idioms that aren't appropriate.  The
idiomatic way of writing this would be:

```
void smooth5( IntVector& v )
{
    IntVector results;
    for ( int i = 0; i < v->size(); i += 2 ) {
        results.push_back( v[i] );
    }
    v.swap( results );
}
```

Any code which involved pointers to vectors is highly
suspicious.